# Placing the camera position inside cube in openGl

Tags: opengl, graphics, 3d

I am trying to create a 3D room. What I am doing is that I am creating a 3D cube and then trying to changing the camera position inside the cube so that it appears as a room. When I make my coordinate vertices as 3 instead of 1 it works but for 1 it doesn't work. 
Why did this happen?

My code for the cube is :

```
glBegin(GL_QUADS);        // Draw The Cube Using quads
glVertex3f(1.0f, 1.0f, -1.0f);    // Top Right Of The Quad (Top)
glVertex3f(-1.0f, 1.0f, -1.0f);    // Top Left Of The Quad (Top)
glVertex3f(-1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f);    // Bottom Left Of The Quad (Top)
glVertex3f(1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f);    // Bottom Right Of The Quad (Top)
glVertex3f(1.0f, -1.0f, 1.0f);    // Top Right Of The Quad (Bottom)
glVertex3f(-1.0f, -1.0f, 1.0f);    // Top Left Of The Quad (Bottom)
glVertex3f(-1.0f, -1.0f, -1.0f);    // Bottom Left Of The Quad (Bottom)
glVertex3f(1.0f, -1.0f, -1.0f);    // Bottom Right Of The Quad (Bottom)
glVertex3f(1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f);    // Top Right Of The Quad (Front)
glVertex3f(-1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f);    // Top Left Of The Quad (Front)
glVertex3f(-1.0f, -1.0f, 1.0f);    // Bottom Left Of The Quad (Front)
glVertex3f(1.0f, -1.0f, 1.0f);    // Bottom Right Of The Quad (Front)
glVertex3f(1.0f, -1.0f, -1.0f);    // Top Right Of The Quad (Back)
glVertex3f(-1.0f, -1.0f, -1.0f);    // Top Left Of The Quad (Back)
glVertex3f(-1.0f, 1.0f, -1.0f);    // Bottom Left Of The Quad (Back)
glVertex3f(1.0f, 1.0f, -1.0f);    // Bottom Right Of The Quad (Back)
glVertex3f(-1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f);    // Top Right Of The Quad (Left)
glVertex3f(-1.0f, 1.0f, -1.0f);    // Top Left Of The Quad (Left)
glVertex3f(-1.0f, -1.0f, -1.0f);    // Bottom Left Of The Quad (Left)
glVertex3f(-1.0f, -1.0f, 1.0f);    // Bottom Right Of The Quad (Left)
glVertex3f(1.0f, 1.0f, -1.0f);    // Top Right Of The Quad (Right)
glVertex3f(1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f);    // Top Left Of The Quad (Right)
glVertex3f(1.0f, -1.0f, 1.0f);    // Bottom Left Of The Quad (Right)
glVertex3f(1.0f, -1.0f, -1.0f);    // Bottom Right Of The Quad (Right)
glEnd();
```

And I am using `gluLookAt(0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,-1.0,0.0,1.0,0.0);`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm assuming you're using a perspective projection and you near plane is greater than one. This would lead to the following scenario where the geometry is behind the near plane and gets clipped:

[image]

Simply reduce the near plane to `0.1` for example. But make sure not to make it too small while the far plane is too big, or you'll lose depth precision and hit "z fighting" issues.